# Pass 3 of the same thing to ExpressJS with a form

Tags: node.js, express

Say I have a form that I want users to be able to submit 3 of the same type of thing; for example: 3 categories.  Is there a way to pass an array?

Something like:    `input(type: "text", name: "user[category]")` *3 times* in my form?  It's probably something like `name: "user[category[]]"` but that's not working for me right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user[category][]`. You can try it out using the repl.

```
var qs = require('qs');
qs.parse('user[category][]=cat1&user[category][]=cat2')
// { user: { category: [ 'cat1', 'cat2' ] } }
```

You can see the [source of qs at their github page](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring). By the way, I think you can only specify a list of string, not a list of object. Look at the [unit tests](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring/blob/master/test/querystring.test.js) for more examples.